# GRPC server and client do not work in Docker

Tags: python, docker, grpc

I have simple GRPC Python code that works in normal Ubuntu environment but failed when trying run it inside a Docker, or using two separate Docker containers. I believe it is related to network IP.

Error message

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1615393363.749930815","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":5390,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1615393363.749924070","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":397,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Command line to start Docker

```
docker run -u root -it --network="host" my:version
```

The server code

```
def server():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    route_guide_pb2_grpc.add_RouteGuideServicer_to_server(
        RouteGuideServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:46001')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()
```

The client code

```
def run():
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:46001') as channel:
        stub = route_guide_pb2_grpc.RouteGuideStub(channel)
        do_something(stub)
```

Comment: Are you confident the server's running in the container? I assume the error message is from the client. What are the server's logs? Please add the Dockerfiles to your question.

Comment: Thanks for asking about the Dockerfile. Indeed I found that problem lies in Dockerfile. I was caused by adding http proxies, removing that and everything works fine.